# Finding and deleting overlapping polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, overlapping-features

I have generated these (green) polygons in ArcMap 10.5.1 by: import XY data > buffer 5 m > minimum bounding geometry (plus a couple of other steps).

image.png
[image: self-intersect of polygons]

The screenshot is a self-intersect of the polygon layer. I need to achieve **zero overlaps** between polygons, by deleting the minimum number of them. I have tens of thousands of polygons.

Can someone suggest a way around this?

I have tried to select the points on the basis of their proximity to each other before buffering - any that are >= 10 m apart would survive the cull.
But my test of ArcGIS nearest neighbour analyses is not promising:

- Average Nearest Neighbor (Spatial Statistics) gives only what the name says - not a feature class with attributes that can be queried / selected
- Calculate Distance Band from Neighbor Count (Spatial Statistics) - likewise

Comment: If you wish to ask for solutions for how to do this in QGIS and/or R then please do that in similar separate questions.

Comment: So in the simplest case you have 2 squares and they partially overlap, are you asking to delete 1 of them to remove the overlap? If you had 3 square all overlapping each other you would need to delete 2, correct? What's the criteria for choosing which to delete?

Comment: Yes, in simplest case I would remove one of the two, but only delete enough of the 3 squares to achieve zero overlap - either one or two deleted. I can use any criteria that work, with a minimum of deletions.