# Finding and deleting overlapping polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

I have generated these (green) polygons in ArcMap 10.5.1 by: import XY data > buffer 5 m > minimum bounding geometry (plus a couple of other steps).

[image: image.png]

self-intersect of polygons

The screenshot is a self-intersect of the polygon layer. I need to achieve zero overlaps between polygons, by deleting the minimum number of them. I have tens of thousands of polygons.

Can someone suggest a way around this?

Related question in arcgis [thread here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386298/finding-and-deleting-overlapping-polygons-using-arcmap?noredirect=1#386298).